# Is it possible to use struct array uniform in VertexShader on GLES2.0?

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

Is it possible to use struct array uniform in VertexShader on GLES2.0?

```
attribute highp vec4 vPosition;

struct TestStruct{
    highp vec4 v;
};
uniform TestStruct tmp[32];

void main() {
    // test code
    gl_Position = vPosition + tmp[31].v;
}
```

I recieved shader compile error.
"uniform variables in vertex shader do not fit in 512 vectors"

My GPU is Qualcomm adreno220.

Do anyone have some information about it?
I am troubled very much.

Thanks.

Comment: I checked your shader code on my device (Galaxy tab with tegra2 GPU), it works... I think it's GPU related..

Comment: Thank you for checking. I also investigated this problem and I agree with you that it is GPU related.

Comment: Yes, it is!

Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16739993/passing-custom-type-struct-uniform-from-qt-to-glsl-using-qglshaderprogram/16740817#16740817

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. There might be a possibility that your array is too big. Try a number below 10 instead of 32.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but I need to use more then 10 units.

Comment: Just try and see if less than 10 works. If it does, then it's a GPU limitation, one you'll have to live with.