# Passing custom type (struct) uniform from Qt to GLSL using QGLShaderProgram

Tags: c++, qt, glsl, shader

I defined a struct for light parameters which contains two vectors. The struct is defined in both C++ and GLSL in an analogous way (note: `QVector3D` encapsulates 3 `float`s, not `double`s):

**C++ host program:**

```
struct LightParameters {
    QVector3D pos;
    QVector3D intensity;
};
```

**Fragment Shader:**

```
struct LightParameters {
    vec3 pos;
    vec3 intensity;
};
```

In the fragment shader, I also define the following uniforms. The numbers of lights is limited to 8, so the uniform array has a constant size (but only `numLights` are actually used):

```
const int maxLights = 8;
uniform int numLights;
uniform LightParameters lights[maxLights];
```

In the host program, I define the lights and pass them to the shader (`QGLShaderProgram`):

```
static const int maxLights = 8;
LightParameters lights[maxLights];

int numLights = 1;
lights[0].pos = {0, 1, 0};
lights[0].intensity = {1, 1, 1};

shaderProgram->bind();
shaderProgram->setUniformValue("numLights", numLights);
shaderProgram->setUniformValueArray("lights", reinterpret_cast<GLfloat*>(lights), maxLights, 6);
shaderProgram->release();
```

The `6` in the last parameter should indicate that each array element uses 6 `GLfloat`s from the raw float array, aka "*tuple size*".

According to the Qt documentation, it should not be possible to use a tuple size of 6 (only 1, 2, 3, 4 are allowed). On the other side, QGLShaderProgram allows to pass in a matrix with up to 4x4 entries. GLSL also allows structs for uniforms which have more than 4 floats in them ([according to this example](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Uniform_%28GLSL%29)).

This leads to the question:

**How can I pass structs of floats / vectors as a uniform array using Qt?** If it's not possible using Qt, I will call the GL function to do this, but I'm interested if Qt can do this for me conveniently.

Of course I tried the code above anyway. It results in all vectors in the struct being set to 0.

When I drop the second parameter in the struct and use a tuple size of 3, the code still does not work! However, when just using `vec3` in the shader (still the struct with one QVector3D in the host program, tuple size = 3), it works.

So the problem seems to be that custom types are handled differently in the OpenGL host program API, but Qt doesn't seem to support it. I currently use two uniform arrays (one for the pos, one for the intensity) as a workaround.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Qt has nothing to do with this.

You *cannot* pass arrays of *structs* as though it were an array of *values*. If you have a uniform array whose type is not [a basic type](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLSL_Type#Basic_types), then every array index and every member of that struct has a [*separate* uniform location with a *separate* uniform name](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Uniform_%28GLSL%29#Uniform_management). Therefore, you must pass each member *separately*.

You must do this:

```
shaderProgram->setUniformValue("lights[0].pos", lights[0].pos);
shaderProgram->setUniformValue("lights[0].intensity", lights[0].intensity);
shaderProgram->setUniformValue("lights[1].pos", lights[1].pos);
shaderProgram->setUniformValue("lights[1].intensity", lights[1].intensity);
shaderProgram->setUniformValue("lights[2].pos", lights[2].pos);
shaderProgram->setUniformValue("lights[2].intensity", lights[2].intensity);
```

And so forth.

Or you could just use a [proper uniform block](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Uniform_Buffer_Object) and dispense with all of that.

Comment: Oh, thank you for clarifying. I should have read the documentation more. I just didn't expect this limitation. So I guess the most straightforward way is to use one array for each original struct field, and not use structs in the shader, which is what I'm doing currently.

Comment: Or you use a uniform block. Really, more people need to use those.

Comment: Thank you for showing me the alternatives. :) I guess uniform blocks are also the solution to the limited number of uniforms?

Answer (score 0):

I use a template function:

```
template<class T> void setUniformArrayValue(QOpenGLShaderProgram *program,
                                       const QString& arrayName,
                                       const QString& varName,
                                       int index,
                                       const T& value)
{
    const char* name = QString("%1[%2].%3")
            .arg(arrayName)
            .arg(index)
            .arg(varName)
            .toStdString().c_str();
    program->setUniformValue(name, value);
}
```

and in the program :

```
for (int i = 0; i < m_lights.size(); i++) {
    setUniformArrayValue<QColor>(program, "lights", "ambient", i, m_lights[i].ambient());
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. However, there is a problem with your code: You call `c_str` on a temporary `std::string`, that invokes undefined behavior, as you have a dangling pointer since the string is deleted before the OpenGL call is happening. Deletion of temporary values happens right after the execution of the statement they're part of (here the initialization of the variable `name`). To correct it, you need to put the `std::string` in a local variable to keep it alive until the `c_str` was used in the OpenGL call. [See this corrected version.](http://ideone.com/1zA8Gc)

Comment: Another hint: the template parameter is not needed to be explicitly written when calling your function. It is automatically deduced by the parameter of type `T` (or `const T&` in this case).

Comment: Thanks for the corrected version. I used my version for a while and never had any trouble with it...for the second hint, if you don't use the explicit template parameter you will get a compilation error (I use mingw with standard options) with double and float parameters for example (If you look at the QVariant::Type enum, there is only double type, no float type). Here the compilation error : **call of overloaded 'setUniformValue(const char*, const double&)' is ambiguous**

Comment: "Undefined behavior" means that anything can happen. It can work. But it doesn't need to work every time. I strongly suggest you correct the error if you don't want your program to crash for a very hard to find reason sometime in the future. For the ambiguity problem, I don't see how explicitly adding `<double>` to the call to your function solves this, as that simply sets `T := double`, which happens in exactly the same way when calling it with a `double` value.